# How to update Rest Api URL?

Tags: android, retrofit

I wanted to update this `private val api` in the function getMenu but i don't know how. My idea was to change the base api url depending of the user interaction with a spinner.

```
@Singleton
class WwMenuRepository @Inject constructor(private val api: ApiInterface,
                                           private val gson: Gson,
                                           private val applicationPreferences: ApplicationPreferences,
                                           @Named("is_stage") private val isStage: Boolean,
                                           cachedValueFactory: CachedValueFactory) : CacheableRepository(cachedValueFactory), MenuRepository {

    override fun getMenu(isLoggedIn: Boolean): Single<List<MenuEntry>> {
        val cachedMenuCall = cachedSingle(methodCacheId = "getMenu", param = isLoggedIn.toString(), singleToCache = api.getMenu().map { mapMenu(it) })

        return if (isLoggedIn) {
            cachedMenuCall
        } else {
            cachedMenuCall.onErrorReturn {
                menuFailover()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun refreshMenu(isLoggedIn: Boolean): Single<List<MenuEntry>> {
        clearCache()
        return getMenu(isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn)
    }

    private fun menuFailover(): List<MenuEntry> {
        val country = applicationPreferences.getSelectedCountry() ?: Country.BRAZIL
        val filename = "menu_$country.json"

        val bufferedReader = javaClass.classLoader?.getResourceAsStream(filename)?.bufferedReader()
        val inputString = bufferedReader.use { it?.readText() }
        return mapMenu(gson.fromJson<MenuResponse>(inputString, MenuResponse::class.java))
    }

    private fun mapMenu(menuResponse: MenuResponse): List<MenuEntry> {
        val menu = menuResponse.data.mapNotNull { it.map() }
        return if (isStage) {
            menu.plus(MenuEntry("Change Shop", MenuEntryType.APPLINK, "changeShop", null))
        } else menu
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you should to write some wrapper like that:

```kotlin
//Base inerface for all apis
interface IApiService {
    val anyApi: IAnyApi
    fun setBaseUrl(url: String)
}

class ApiService: IApiService {
lateinit var _anyApi: IAnyApi
override val anyApi: IAnyApi
get() = _anyApi
init {
//it must initialize _apiService for avoid problems
setBaseUrl(DEFAULT_URL)
}
fun setBaseUrl(url: String) {
//initialize retrofit and recreate anyApi
...
}
}
```

Than you can inject IApiService and call methods like
apiService.anyApi.getAnything()